# php preg_match как запретить такие символы как \ / : * ? " ' < > |

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Привет помогите с preg_match в php как написать выражение что бы не содержались символы такие как

```
\ / : * ? " ' < > |
```

напишите решение пожалуйста.

Я написал данное выражение

```
if (preg_match("/[\/\:\*\?\"\'\<\>\|]/", $nickname)) echo 'Запрещённые символы';
```

но оно пропускает такие символы как

```
\ " < >
```

помогите пожалуйста.

Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Что значит "запретить?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слишком много экранирования там где не нужно и нет экранирования там где нужно.

Вам нужно заэкранировать два символа `\` и символ кавычки

```
if (preg_match('~[\\\/:*?"\'<>|]~', $str))
  echo 'Alert';
```

Comment: И ещё чтобы указать знак \ перед ним нужно поставить двойную экраниронизацию

Comment: @ПолосатыйТигр Зачем? Я же привел полностью работающий код. [Код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a5df3ce5019de1822fcea9e7882c1f11fcf3fad)

Comment: если ты попробуешь проверить знак \ то он будет его игнорировать

Comment: @ПолосатыйТигр вы правы. Поправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо что помог со скриптом.